# Calling and retrieving numpy array multiple times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code is something like this:

```
def something():
   """this function will call the `get_array` multiple times until the
      end of the array and is fixed (cannot change this function)"""
   #skip some functions and initialization there
   #only used to get the result of `get_array`
   a.get_array()
```

In a separate file:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, count=-1):
        self.count = count

    def cal_array(self, parameters):
        """calculate array"""
        return array

    def get_array(self, parameters):
        if self.count == -1:
            self.cal_array(parameters)
            # some methods to store array there
        else:
            self.count += 1
            return array[self.count,:]
```

I want to know if there is a way to calculate the numpy array once and save it for future use (calling from another function).

I know I can save the numpy array to the disk or use a global dict to save the array, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I think this depends on what you want to do with the array inside `something`. Furthermore, your example is incorrect, or at least incomplete. You cannot call `a.get_array()` because it is not a static method, you need to initiate an instance first.

Comment: @iled I need to do some calculations using the result of get_array (which should be a row of array calculated in `cal_array`. Yep, I know I didn't initialize the class because `something` is a function inside another class and I don't want to write the whole function but I will add a note. Thanks for pointing out.